# How can I run two while loops together when using the time module in Python

Tags: python, pygame

Essentially I am using pygame. My gameloop has a lot of event handling and controls the position of the sprite and such.

Every 1 second snowball sprites will come in from the left of the screen, however when inputting this while loop in the game function, only that while loop is run, and the game just freezes because it is only waiting 1 second and updating the sprite, not focusing on the event handling or anything.

Even when using two different functions, when running the snowball function the program simply can't focus on both functions, and remains stuck on the snowball function.

I don't want to use anything complicated, just a simply elegant solution. I have looked at threading but it looks too complicated and i'm new to python.

Comment: If you want to do two things at a time in two different parts of your code, you're going to have to use threads. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `time` module.

Simply create an event, and tell pygame to put that event into the event queue every second (using the `pygame.time.set_timer` function). Then you can handle it in your mainloop like every other event.

Here's a simple example. It is using custom events with `pygame.time.set_timer` and a single main loop, without needing the `time` module:

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
player, dir, size = pygame.Rect(100,100,20,20), (0, 0), 20
MOVEEVENT, APPLEEVENT, trail = pygame.USEREVENT+1, pygame.USEREVENT+2, []
pygame.time.set_timer(MOVEEVENT, 250)
pygame.time.set_timer(APPLEEVENT, 1000)
apples=[]
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]: dir = 0, -1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]: dir = -1, 0
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: dir = 0, 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]: dir = 1, 0

    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): break
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == MOVEEVENT: # this event happens every 250 ms
            trail.append(player.inflate((-10, -10)))
            trail = trail[-5:]
            player.move_ip(*[v*size for v in dir])
        if e.type == APPLEEVENT: # this event happens every 1000 ms
            apples.append(pygame.rect.Rect(random.randint(0, 30) * 10, random.randint(0, 30) * 10, 10, 10))

    screen.fill((0,120,0))
    for t in trail:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), t)
    for a in apples:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,100), a)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), player)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This should give you an idea on how about resolving your issue. Don't use `time.sleep`, it just blocks your loop.

Comment: I'm completely confused by this. Is there any tutorial anywhere explaining this? I don't understand how I could use this to replace a while loop which pumps out a sprite every second

Comment: @user3853755 I updated my answer with a simpler example. I creates a new rect every second with an event.

Comment: @user3853755 If you provide your code here or on another web site (like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)), it would be a lot easier to provide a solution for your problem.